# Cut a string before a character in better way in php

Tags: php, string

I have a very simple question about php.

I have this string:

```
This is a simple string | badword is here
```

And I need this:

```
The is a simple string
```

So,

I have used this code below:

```
$word = substr($word, 0, strpos($word, '|'));
```

and if I use that code, I have to check is there any `|` char in the string, If yes delete it.

So it's very very low speed and I can't use it .

What is the fastest way to get the result, without checking if the `|` char is or is not in the main string?

Comment: what do you mean very very low speed? do you have a benchmark for this?

Comment: @Ghost I want to know is there any other way to do that?

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense - I want to remove 'x', I don't know where 'x' is, but I don't want to search for 'x'.  There are other ways of doing this (regular expressions), but fundamentally it's still going to have to search for the things you need to remove.

Comment: Strpos iterates the string and substr has to do also. This is not ideal, regexp is not ideal as well because it needs to parse strings. I guess Bifo looks for the absolute ideal solution. Unfortunately it seems that there is not such routine in php, that is precoded. Precoded routine are C programmed and usually faster than coding a substrAt(...) yourself in PHP. So I would believe that the substr+strpos is faster than a php-programmed ideal substrAt routine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this example, alternatively, you could use `strtok()` also:

```
$string = 'This is a simple sting | badword is here';
$result = strtok($string, '|');
echo $result; // This is a simple sting
```

Comment: thanks, is there any way to check it for more than 1 time? for example i want to check and remove after `|` and `/`.

Comment: @Bifo i don't think this route will handle multiple delimiters, you might have more power when regex is involved

Answer (score 4):

You can use explode() to separate string between specific character.

```
$string = 'This is a simple sting | badword is here';

$var = explode('|', $string);

echo $var[0]; // This is a simple sting
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use explode() function

```
$string = 'This is a simple sting | badword is here';
$pieces = explode("|", $string );
echo $pieces[0];    // will display This is a simple sting
```

Answer (score 0):

> Best way is to use explode() function.please follow the links below.

[explode tutorials 1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

[explode tutorials 2](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/php-string-explode.php)

```
**try this example :**

$text= 'This is a simple sting | badword is here';

$var = explode('|', $text);

echo $var[0];
```